# ember Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function when loading in store

Tags: ember.js, websocket, store

I'm using ember to display data received from my golang server. The data are in JSON form.
so I opened a websocket and tried to push the message received in the store but i got this error: 
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

this is my app.js:

```
    App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true

})
/******************************* Post Template **************************************/

//Define a route for the template "post"
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route("post", { path: "/post" });

});

//Post Model
App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
     name: DS.attr('string' ),
     number: DS.attr('string')
});


DS.SocketAdapterMixin = Ember.Mixin.create({
    uri: 'ws://localhost:8081/',
    init: function(){
        this.ws = new WebSocket(this.uri);

        // callbacks
        this.ws.onopen = function() {
          console.log('Connection established /all');
        };
        this.ws.onclone = function() {
          console.log('Connection closed /' + 'all');
        };
        this.ws.onmessage = function(data) {

         this.get('store').load(App.Post, data)
          console.log(data);

        };

        this._super();
    },

    initialize: function() {
        console.log('SocketAdapterMixin::initialize');
        this._super();
  }
});


DS.SocketAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend(DS.SocketAdapterMixin, {
  init: function() {
    this._super();
    console.log('SocketAdapter');
  }

});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.SocketAdapter.extend({});

// Use the adapter in the store

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  revision: 13,
  adapter: DS.SocketAdapter.create({})
});
```

and my index.html:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Ember.js Example Application</title>

   <script src="js/libs/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.1.2.js"></script>
   <script src="js/libs/ember-1.5.1.js"></script>
   <script src="js/libs/Ember_Data.js"></script>
   <script src="js/app.js"></script>
   <script src="js/router.js"></script>
 <!--  <script src="js/models/model.js"></script> -->

</head>
<body>
<h1>Bonjour </h1>


<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    Hello, {{firstName}} {{lastName}}<br/>

    <nav>
  {{#link-to 'post'}}Post{{/link-to}}
  </nav>

     <div>
      {{outlet}}
    </div>

</script>



<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    <h2>My Wrappers</h2>
    <ul>
    {{#each post in model}}
        <li>{{post.number}}</li>

    {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script></p>


  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="post">
     <h2>My Post</h2>
    <ul>
        <li> Zied</li>
        <li> Farah</li>
    </ul>
  </script>


<script type="text/javascript">

</script>


</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I suggest that the problem is in this.get('store'), it prints undefined when i try to print its value.

Answer (score 0):

You don't define the store in Ember Data since Ember Data 1.0 beta 1+.

<s>App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
      revision: 13,
      adapter: DS.SocketAdapter.create({})
    });</s>

Just using this will suffice:

```
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.SocketAdapter;
```

The store is passed in to the `find` functions, if you want you can use it then.  Additionally you would be out of scope inside of `onmessage`, but that's beside the point.

#### Recommendation

Since your program is two fold I'd recommend creating your adapters/transport layer using dependency injection.  Here's a rough draft

#### Transport

```
DS.SocketTransport = Ember.Object.extend({
    uri: 'ws://localhost:8081/',
    type: 'post',
    ws: null,
    store: null,
    init: function(){
        var uri = this.get('uri'),
            type = this.get('type'),
            store = this.get('store'),
            ws = new WebSocket(uri);

        // callbacks
        ws.onopen = function() {
          console.log('Connection established /all');
        };
        ws.onclone = function() {
          console.log('Connection closed /' + 'all');
        };
        ws.onmessage = function(data) {
          // if this is random post data, side load
          store.load('post', data)
          console.log(data);
        };

        this._super();
    }
});
```

#### Web Socket Adapter

```
App.MyWsAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  transport: null,
  find: function(store, type, id) {
    var transport = this.get('transport');
    // Do your thing here
    return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      // use the transport here to send a message/get a message, containing
      // the json for the type and id mentioned above then use
      //resolve(json);
    });

  },

});
```

#### Dependency Injection

```
App.initializer({
    name: "transport",
    after:['store'],

    initialize: function (container, application) {
      var store = container.lookup('store:main'),
          postTransport = application.PostTransport.create({store:store, type:'post'});

        register("my:postTranspot", postTransport);
        application.PostAdapter = App.MyWsAdapter.create({
          transport: postTransport
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you have an example please! it's not clear for me

Comment: I tossed up some example of the general idea, untested, but should give you an idea.